# How to sort array elements?

Tags: arrays, sorting, awk

I have a file

```
     2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:30:46 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44
        2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:30:46 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 2$
2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:30:46 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 44
        2001:778:0:1::21 - - [16/Sep/2011:12:32:15 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66643
        88.222.10.7 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 66643
        88.222.10.1 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 14$
     88.222.10.1 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 14$
     88.222.10.1 - - [17/Sep/2011:23:39:25 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 14$
        88.222.10.7 - - [18/Sep/2011:13:45:39 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

And I need to count the duplicates IP addresses

```
 awk -F "- -" '{dups[$1]++} END{for (num in dups) {print num,dups[num]}}' myFile
```

So now I have

```
2001:778:0:1::21 4
88.222.10.7 2
88.222.10.1 3
```

And I want to sort everything So my result should be

```
  2001:778:0:1::21 4
    88.222.10.1 3
    88.222.10.7 2
```

But I don't know how to sort arrays? IS it possible to do that?

Comment: pipe to sort is an option

Comment: If gawk use `asort`.

Answer (score 2):

This is most straightforward with GNU awk 4.0+, which has a mechanism for [sorted array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html):

```
awk '{dups[$1]++} END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"; for(num in dups) {print num,dups[num]}}' filename
```

That is:

```
{ dups[$1]++ }
END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc";  # <-- here: Array traversal in
                                            #     numerically descending order
                                            #     of values
  for(num in dups) {
    print num,dups[num]
  }
}
```

If GNU awk is not available, pipe through `sort`:

```
awk '{dups[$1]++} END{ for(num in dups) {print num,dups[num]}}' filename | sort -t ' ' -rgk 2
```

Note that I removed the custom field separator because it didn't seem necessary (and even harmful if the number of leading whitespace varied). If you want to keep it for some reason, you'll have to give `sort` the `-b` option in addition to `-t ' ' -rgk 2` to ignore the leading whitespace in awk's output.